# Llenar un dropdown de JSN Uniform

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3

Estoy  creando un formulario con **`JSN Uniform`** en el cual tengo un dropdown que debe llenarse con valores desde una base de datos, he tratado con varios videos pero no he logrado resultados.
¿Como puedo llenar mi dropdown de JSN umiform con datos desde mi BD?
¿Esta bien escribir el codigo script cuando se displaye el formulario?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$conexion=mysql_connect('localhost', 'estefani','3st3f4n1')  or die ("No se puede conectar".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("letritastv", $conexion) or die ("No se puede conectar".mysql_error());
$sentencia= mysql_query("SELECT nameimg FROM a_t3s1s_image ORDER BY nameimg ASC");
$query=mysql_query($sentencia);



while ($arreglo=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ 
echo "<option value=' ".$arreglo['codigo']." ' ";
if($_POST['4']==$arreglo ['codigo'])
echo " SELECTED ";
echo ">";
echo $arreglo['4']; ------> **se supone que 4 es el nombre del dropdown**
echo "</option>"; 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida Estefani!!! si pudieras facilitar parte del codigo php, para que te pueda ayudar, seria ideal

Comment: Segun veo en JSN Uniform se puede crear script php y añadirlos directamente como se muestra en la segunda imagen que anexe, el codigo esta debajo de ella.

Comment: Podrias intentar utilizando JQuery con Ajax para que al cargar la pagina se ejecute un Ajax que vaya y haga la consulta y te retorne tus opciones y las anexe a tu select.